# Removing parts of a Regex statement

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, is it possible to extract only certain parts of a regex statement? For example, if I have a regex statement

```
/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{/
```

is it possible for me to remove the fullstop and curly brackets found without ruining the match?

Let me put it this way;

I'm searching through my stylesheet to find all classes using the above regex statement, so classes always start with a fullstop and I need to find the first curly bracket of the class. Once I've found it, I only need the name of the class without the fullstop and curly bracket to store in a Hash Map.

So is there a way of removing these from my answer? I've tried the .replace method, but for that to work I need the actual string, I can't be using a variable that I've stored it in. I'll attach my code as well to help you guys understand further. Thanks in advance!

```
if (rules[j].constructor === CSSMediaRule) {
                mqrule = rules[j].cssText;
                console.log(mqrule);
                lines = (mqrule).split('\n');
                for (var c = 0; c < lines.length; c++) {
                    if (lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{/)) {
                        console.log("It works!");
                        console.log(lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{/));
                        newKey = lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{/);

                        //I'VE TRIED IT 2 WAYS BUT NEITHER WORK.
                        newKey = newKey.replace(".", "");
                        newKey = newKey.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/g);
                        //ANY SUGGESTIONS?

                        MQHash[newkey] = newValue;
                        console.log(MQHash);
                    }
                }
                mqls['mql' + j] = window.matchMedia(rules[j].media.mediaText);
                mqls['mql' + j].addListener(mediaChange);
                mediaChange(mqls['mql' + j]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a catching group:

```
/\.(\w+)\s\{|\.(\-\w+)\s\{/
```

For each `()` you will get the content in an array.

You should use this because it has the `g` global flag:

```
re = /\.(\w+)\s\{|\.(\-\w+)\s\{/;
matches = re.exec(css);
```

Now matches is an array containing all caught groups.
The one you are interested in is at index 1 because at index 0 is always the whole text you matched up against.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand your nedds, but how about:

```
/\.-?(\w+)\s\{/
```

The result you want is in group 1.

Comment: Thanks for your input! (No sarcasm intended)